# Calculation Logic In Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have an rails app wherein I need to pick up data from user through UI store them in a DB which I am able to do without any hiccups. However I need to retrieve the stored data from DB and perform some calculations over them and then plot them using a graph library.

I read that calculation logic generally belongs to the model, hence my model file code is listed as below. But now I am wondering as to how to pass my resultant arrays to an view and get it plotted. Basically I am not getting the interconnection right. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

```
class Shot < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.calculate(param)
    #fetch_all_three_shots
    #Performs Query aginst DB and returns the same data structure depicted in 'shots' array
    #shots = Shot.all.collect{|a| [a.c1,a.c2,a.c3,a.c4,a.c5,a.c6,a.c7,a.c8,a.c9,a.c10,a.c11,a.c12]} 
    #shots = [[1.55, 1.58, 1.59, 1.58, 1.53, 1.57, 1.57, 1.55, 1.57, 1.6, 1.62, 1.6],
    #     [1.54, 1.55, 1.58, 1.57, 1.49, 1.56, 1.55, 1.55, 1.54, 1.59, 1.61, 1.6],
    #     [1.55, 1.57, 1.59, 1.57, 1.51, 1.56, 1.56, 1.55, 1.56, 1.59, 1.62, 1.59]]
    shots = fetch_all_three_shots

    #Declaration of Array for all Data Sets Goes here...
    cavity_arr = Array.new
    avgpartwt_arr = Array.new
    fillseq_arr = Array.new
    imbalance_arr = Array.new
    max_imbalance_arr = Array.new
    intermediate_arr = Array.new
    fillmeanwt_arr = Array.new
    statistics_shotwise_arr = Array.new
    statistics_bof_arr = Array.new 

    #Formulation of Cavity Array Goes Here...
    cavity_arr = (1 .. 12).to_a

    #Looping for Calculation of Average Part Weight Goes Here...
    for i  in (0 .. (shots[0].size - 1))
        avgpartwt_arr.push((shots[0][i] + shots[1][i] + shots[2][i]) / 3)
    end

    #Rank Calculation Logic Goes Here....
    fillseq_arr = avgpartwt_arr.map{|value| avgpartwt_arr.select{|item| item > value}.size + 1}

    #Looping for Calculation of Percentage Imbalance Goes Here...  
    for i in (0 .. (avgpartwt_arr.size - 1))
        imbalance_arr.push(((avgpartwt_arr.max - avgpartwt_arr[i]) / avgpartwt_arr.max) * 100)
    end

    #Looping for Maximum Imbalance Array Goes Here...
    for i in (0 .. (imbalance_arr.size - 1))
        if imbalance_arr[i] != imbalance_arr.max
            max_imbalance_arr.push(0)
        else
            max_imbalance_arr.push(cavity_arr[i])
        end
    end

    #Formulation of Intermediate Array Goes Here...
    intermediate_arr = [((avgpartwt_arr.mean).round(3))] * 12

    #Formulation of Fill Weight Mean Array Goes Here...
    for i in (0 .. (avgpartwt_arr.size - 1))
        fillmeanwt_arr.push(((intermediate_arr[i] - avgpartwt_arr[i]) / intermediate_arr[i]) * 100)
    end

    #Looping for Calculation of Shotwise Statistical Parameters Across Shots Goes Here...
    for i in (0 .. (shots.size - 1))
        statistics_shotwise_arr.push( [shots[i].max, shots[i].min, shots[i].range, shots[i].mean, shots[i].standard_deviation] )
    end

    #Formulation of Balance of Fill Parameters Goes Here...
    cavmaximbalance =  max_imbalance_arr.max
    maximbalance = imbalance_arr.max 
    avgimbalance = imbalance_arr.mean 
    rangedrop = (((statistics_shotwise_arr[0][2] - statistics_shotwise_arr[2][2]) / statistics_shotwise_arr[0][2]) * 100)

  end
  scope :fetch_all_three_shots , -> {all.collect{|a| [a.c1, a.c2, a.c3, a.c4, a.c5 ,a.c6, a.c7, a.c8, a.c9, a.c10, a.c11, a.c12]}}
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def some_action
    @some_variable = Shot.calculate(params)

    render :show_action
  end
end
```

`@some_variable`, which is the return value of the `Shot.calculate(params)`, is available in the view.

Comment: Hi Dharam, Can I declare arrays like i have done directly on the model file. Second question is will my fetch_all_three_shots in its current form retrieve data from DB and make it available in my 'shots' variable? I am a newbie to rails and hence this noob questions.

Comment: Yes, you can declare `arrays` like you have declared in the model file. But the only thing that is returned from this method is `rangedrop` as that is the last line of the method. `ruby` does implicit return the last statement of the method. So you want those `arrays` to be available, then you need to declare them as the last statement, something like [cavity_arr, avgpartwt_arr, ...].

Comment: As `fetch_all_three_shots` is a scope, which `rails` makes it available as class method and as you declared `calculate` as class method, I don't see any problem. Overall, this may not be a good design though, as you have one method doing too many things, which will be difficult to test.

Comment: I want all my resultant arrays to be available. I'll try your suggestion.What about my cavmaximbalance and other variables I have in my model file. will they be avilable in my view.???

Comment: I have an another doubt. What should I pass in place of params in the controller logic that you have written. I know its a parameter. I am asking more from  my app perspective.

Comment: All those variables you declared in `calculate` method are called `local` variables, their scope (in other wards, availability) is limited to the method. Whatever you want to make them available outside the method, you need to explicitly return them as the last statement. You could return them as a big array, for ex: [cavity_arr, ..., cavmaximbalance, ..], or better as a hash, for ex: {cavity_arr: cavity_arr, cavmaximbalance: cavmaximbalance}, so that you know how to retrieve them in the view easily.

Comment: You need to pass, whatever you need inside the method `calculate`. But looks like you are not depending on any information from the controller, so you don't need to pass any parameters to the method.

Comment: My controller code looks like as in the below given listing http://pastebin.com/FE2QG2A8